# Wordpress post background image bleeds through on Category Page

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, posts, twentytwenty

I am using the twentytwenty theme and all my post titles show a strip of the background image behind the title that stretches across the page. Here is a snippet. [this is the title of the post and the strip behind it is part of the background header image of the post and it stretches from one end of the page to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU3fZ.png)

To delete the background image from the post is to delete the background image from all pages.  Is there a CSS fix, or do I create a custom post template and custom header in the child theme for posts only?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the HTML for this page.  You should be able to either set a background colour on the title element, or perhaps adjust the overflow of the container with the background image, etc.  What is the desired effect you want and what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately I do not understand what you are trying to do. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   . This is just guessing, because I need more information. But you can style the h1 headline with css using `h1.entry-title, h2.entry-title { /* your style */ }`

Comment: Thanks to all...i will take the time to read up and ask intelligently tomorrow so I don't waste anyone's time....thanks again...I appreciate it!